# how can mute current scene for ever in unity c#

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

have Toggle on/off for mute volume and this is my function :

```
public    void Mm(bool vv)
     {
         if (vv)
         {
             AudioListener.volume = 0;
         }
         else 
         {
             AudioListener.volume = 1;
         }
     }
```

all thing work well but problem is : when i mute and go another scene , when come back in this scene again volume not mute!

Answer (score 2):

Create a `SoundManager` script like below and place it in your **current scene** :

```
public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
        AudioListener.volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("volume",0);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        AudioListener.volume = 1;
    }

    public void Mute(bool vv)
    {
        if (vv)
        {
            AudioListener.volume = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            AudioListener.volume = 1;
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("volume",AudioListener.volume);
        PlayerPrefs.Save()
    }
}
```

Comment: register `Mute()` method on your toggle's value change event.

Comment: so its like my way . still had my problem with your way . so i mute and its ok but when i go another scene . that scene mute to . i want just mute this scene

Comment: not help! just like that . still had that problem :(

Comment: This is actually a really good solution. Remember to use `PlayerPrefs.Save()` to save the volume float.

Comment: @erfan how are you switching between scenes?

Comment: public void LoadScene(int level)
 {
  Application.LoadLevel (level);
 } my first scene is 0 and secondary scene is 1

Comment: again just mute two scene! when i mute and go secondary scene my secondary scene is mute to!